# New Row inserting using jQuery/AJAX in PHP and while loop

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-ui

I have a jQuery function and php file as below.

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".book_id_class").click(function(){
    $("td:hidden").show();
    });
    });
    </script>

    <table>
    <tr>
    <td class="text-center">Book ID</td>
    <?php for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++){ ?>
    <td class="text-center">Month <?php echo $i; ?></td>
    <?php } ?>
    </tr>
    <?php  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($book_result) ) {  ?>

    <tr>
    <td class="text-center"><a id="book_id" class="book_id_class"> + <?php echo $row['book_id']; ?></a></td>
    <td style="display:none">N/A</td>
    <?php for($j=1;$j<=12;$j++){ ?>
    <td>
    <?php echo $row['month_'.$j]; } ?>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </table>
```

The above code produce the below output.

```
    Book ID     Month 1     Month 2  . . .          Month 12

    + 123           50          40                      90
    + 345           30          50                      20
```

Now, What I'm trying to do is.

When the BookID(for ex: Book ID: 123) is clicked, it should insert a new row for that particular Book.

The expected output should be like this

```
    Book ID     Month 1     Month 2  . . .          Month 12

    + 123           50          40                      90
                    N/A         N/A                     N/A

    + 345           30          50                      20
```

How can I achieve this. I'm bad with jQuery and any help will be very useful.

Thanks,
Kimz

Comment: you mean you want a new row without the Book ID value?

Comment: @AminJafari - yes without the book ID value

Answer (score 0):

first of all, ids should be unique so you should drop `id="book_id"` from your code.

then change your html to this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <td class="text-center">Book ID</td>
    <?php for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++){ ?>
    <td class="text-center">Month <?php echo $i; ?></td>
    <?php } ?>
    </tr>

    <tr>

    <td class="text-center"><a id="book_id" class="book_id_class"> + <?php echo $row['book_id']; ?></a></td>
    <?php  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($book_result) ) {  ?>
    <td style="display:none">N/A</td>
    <?php for($j=1;$j<=12;$j++){ ?>
    <td>
    <?php echo $row['month_'.$j]; } ?>
    </td>
    <?php } ?>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

then you can add the row like this:

```
$(document).on('click','.book_id_class',function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().next().css('display','block');
});
```